# Why can't I open and use Sox-o-matic 1.1.10?

Tags: software, sox

I was able to use Sox-o-matic 1.1.10 before but this pop-up suddenly occurred after a few times. Any idea what happened and what I could do to use this software again?

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Since this has to do with some JRE (Java Runtime Environment) you could possibly try to re-install the latest JRE (from here for Windows: https://www.java.com/en/). Alternatively, you could send an e-mail to the manufacturer (which I believe is the right thing to do). They will, most probably, provide guidance.

Answer (score 3):

Sox-o-matic depends on Amazon Corretto 8, which comes bundled with Sox-o-matic. Somehow your Sox-o-matic configuration got messed up, so you might want to consider deleting it and downloading a fresh copy. Instructions for installing Sox-o-matic can be found in https://www.birds.cornell.edu/ccb/sox-o-matic/.

If that doesn't help, I would suggest contacting the staff of the K. Lisa Yang Center for Conservation Bioacoustics by emailing raven_support@cornell.edu.